# Button on mid of a column

Tags: css, r, shiny

I am currently looking for a way to put a button on the middle of a bigger column...

So here is the codes I tried :

```
column(
  width = 6,
  div(
    style="display:inline-block",
    actionButton(
      "nextpg",
      span("Next Page", style="size:100px"),
      width = 250,
      height = 50
      )
    )
  )
```

or

**ui.R**

```
column(
  width = 6,
  div(
    class="nxtBtn",
    actionButton(
      "nextpg",
      span("Next Page", style="size:100px"),
      width = 250,
      height = 50
      )
    )
  )
```

**custom.CSS**

```
.nxtBtn {
  position: center;
  display: inline-block;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Unfortunately, none of those ways worked.

Please, could you find the solution?

**Edit:**

Here is the solution I found :

```
column(
  width = 6,
  align = "center",
  actionButton(
    "nextpg",
    span("Next Page", style="size:100px"),
    width = 250,
    height = 50
  )
)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.